# Extbase - How to „restore“ an ObjectStorage on __wakeup()

Tags: serialization, typo3, extbase

On __sleep() i throw away a models property (ObjectStorage of Product). How can this property be restored on __wakeup(), containig all the related products it had before serialization?

Comment: This might be related to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91196 - the resulting patch https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/repository/revisions/65be85b110833d7eb56a87a6544b4d6b53ab33fc implents __sleep and __wakeup functions in  typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/FileReference.php for proper serialization - have a look at getFileObject() , maybe this could solve the problem.